# Modify outer IP header of GENEVE encapsulated packets

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tunnel, openvswitch, xdp-bpf

For my project, I want to insert a timestamp option into outer IP header of a GENEVE encapsulated packet. I tried with a BPF program which attached into egress TC hook of a GENEVE vport of OVS. My BPF program is below but it inserts option field into inner ip header. So, I have 2 questions:

1. Can use BPF to insert IP option into IP outer header?
2. If it is possible, How to do it?

```
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#ifndef __section
# define __section(NAME)                  \
        __attribute__((section(NAME), used))
#endif

#ifndef __inline
# define __inline                         \
        inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#endif

#ifndef lock_xadd
# define lock_xadd(ptr, val)              \
        ((void)__sync_fetch_and_add(ptr, val))
#endif

#ifndef BPF_FUNC
# define BPF_FUNC(NAME, ...)              \
        (*NAME)(__VA_ARGS__) = (void *)BPF_FUNC_##NAME
#endif

#define OPT_LEN 4
#define IP_HDL 20

static int BPF_FUNC(skb_adjust_room, struct __sk_buff *skb, __s32 len_diff, __u32 mode, __u64 flags);
//static int BPF_FUNC(skb_vlan_push, struct __sk_buff *skb, uint16_t proto, uint16_t vlan_tci);

__section("egress")
int push_tun_opt(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    __be32 *opt;
    volatile void *data, *data_end;
    int ret = TC_ACT_OK;
    //skb_vlan_push(skb,0x8100,0x1);
    skb_adjust_room(skb, size(OPT_LEN), BPF_ADJ_ROOM_NET, BPF_F_ADJ_ROOM_ENCAP_L3_IPV4);
    data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    eth = (void *)data;
    iph = (void *)(eth+1);
    opt = (void *)(iph+1);
    if ((void *)(opt+1) > data_end)
        goto out;
    *opt = 0x1234abcd;
out:
    return ret;
}

char __license[] __section("license") = "GPL";
```

**Packet before insertion**
[image: Before]

**Packet after insertion**
[image: After]

**BPF program with none flags**

```
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>

#ifndef __section
# define __section(NAME)                  \
        __attribute__((section(NAME), used))
#endif

#ifndef __inline
# define __inline                         \
        inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#endif

#ifndef lock_xadd
# define lock_xadd(ptr, val)              \
        ((void)__sync_fetch_and_add(ptr, val))
#endif

#ifndef BPF_FUNC
# define BPF_FUNC(NAME, ...)              \
        (*NAME)(__VA_ARGS__) = (void *)BPF_FUNC_##NAME
#endif

#define OPT_LEN 4
#define IP_HDL 20

static int BPF_FUNC(skb_adjust_room, struct __sk_buff *skb, __s32 len_diff, __u32 mode, __u64 flags);
//static int BPF_FUNC(skb_vlan_push, struct __sk_buff *skb, uint16_t proto, uint16_t vlan_tci);
static int BPF_FUNC(skb_store_bytes, struct __sk_buff *skb, __s32 offset, const void *from, __u32 len, __u64 flags);

__section("egress")
int push_tun_opt(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    __be32 *opt;
    volatile void *data, *data_end;
    
    int ret = TC_ACT_OK;
    //skb_vlan_push(skb,0x8100,0x1);
    skb_adjust_room(skb, OPT_LEN, BPF_ADJ_ROOM_NET, 0);
    data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    eth = (void *)data;
    iph = (void *)(eth+1);
    opt = (void *)(iph+1);
    if ((void *)(opt+1) > data_end)
        goto out;

    *opt = 0x1234abcd;
    //skb_store_bytes(skb, sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr), &opt, OPT_LEN, BPF_F_RECOMPUTE_CSUM);

out:
    return ret;
}

char __license[] __section("license") = "GPL";
```

**geneve interface**
[image: geneve interface]
**Edit 1:** I added 2 images: a ping packet is encapsulated in GENEVE tunnel before and after using tc-bpf program.

**Edit 2:** I added BPF program with 0 flags.

Comment: Not sure you need the flag `BPF_F_ADJ_ROOM_ENCAP_L3_IPV4` in your case. Did you try passing `0` instead?

Comment: @JustinIurman You are right, I don't need this flag. I dived into skb_adjust_room() function source code in filter.c and found that packets which encapsuled will be ignore when call skb_adjust_room() function with ENCAP_L3 flags. But when I try 0 flag, option field is still inserted into inner ip header.

Comment: That's weird. Could you provide (e.g., in Wireshark) a packet before and after the insertion, so that it makes things easier to debug?

Comment: @JustinIurman I added image of packet before and after insertion in Wireshark.

Comment: Are you sure that, at the point you are hooking your BPF program, you are seeing the encapsulated packet and not the inner packet before encapsulation? It would explain what's going on here.

Comment: @pchaigno I'm not sure about that. When I create a geneve tunnel port in kernel datapath of OVS, an interface named "genev_sys_6081" will appear when tested with the command "ip a". I guess that whole encapsulated packets go in and out OVS will be transmitted through this interface. So, I attached BPF program into tc egress hook of this interface.

Comment: To confirm, you could update the BPF program to print something different in `bpf_trace_printk` depending on whether the packet is encapsulated or not.

Comment: Pretty sure the packet gets first through your bpf program and then through the geneve encapsulation. Would be the only reason that makes sense, as @pchaigno mentioned. On a side note, don't forget to convert values you add to big endian in packets.